# Storyboards: How to add outlets to a prototype UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, uikit, uistoryboard

I have added prototype cell in one of the controllers that is part of the storyboard I'm designing. It has various labels, buttons, bells and whistles.
But how do I know create outlets to that cell's elements? If I click the assistant in Xcode, it will show me the dummy source of my inherited UITableViewController and not of the "`DetailsCell`" which inherits from `UITableViewCell` and is specified in the custom class input field in IB.

I could of course use `ViewWithTag()` but I'd rather have something strong typed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With any object you can create with IB, you can assign it to a different class (one that you wrote).  This is not different for cells.  In the same way you can make IB instantiate MyFooView instead of UIView (MyFooView being derived from UIView), you can do the same for the cells.

Click your cell, click the 3rd icon on the shelf to the right.  You will see a section called "Custom Class" and a text field called Class.  Select the new class you've just created that is derived from UITableViewCell (let's call it MyCell).  You can add IBOutlets to the MyCell class.

Comment: The difference is: I was used to just drag & drop a connection from a view into the code and it would create the outlet automatically. However this does not work with subclasses of UITableViewCell. But after adding the outlet in code, I was able to connect.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create a class DetailedCell and add IBOutlets to that class.

Then in the Storyboard/IB, assign that class to the prototype cell and those outlets will be available to fill.